# inheritance relationship No identifier specified for entity

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

```
class A implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    Integer id;
    ...
    // constructor getter and setter 
}

@Entity
class B extends A{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column
    String name;
    @Column
    String age;
    ...
    //constructors, getters and setters
}
```

As you see above, class `A` extends  from class `B`, `B` should have the identifier `id` inheritance from `A`. but i got the `No identifier specified for entity: com.d.e.B`

what did i missed?  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You missed the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation on A, to tell Hibernate/JPA that properties and JPA annotations found in A must be considered.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, `@MapperSuperclass` will work.
If you have entity relationships (one to many, many to one, etc...) the A class should be defined as an **entity** and the `@Inheritance` annotation should be used instead.

I had the same error ("No identifier specified for entity") because my A class had the `@Inheritance` annotation but not the `@Entity` annotation